# how to install mathutils

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have already installed the c++ tools and updated the tools by `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but installing of `mathutils` does not work

> Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\33749\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\33749\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jbsp1j3h\mathutils_62d38e7d44a44d75978e68055dbcc440\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\33749\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jbsp1j3h\mathutils_62d38e7d44a44d75978e68055dbcc440\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\33749\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bc4w9hy_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\33749\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\mathutils' Check the logs for full command outpu

Comment: Add the complete log

Comment: Installing libraries must be simple, but there might be some dependancies

Comment: @MadanRaj how i can Add the complete log

Comment: @Marouane Amzil -How did you install "c++ tools"? After I installed the VS from the link provided in the terminal and restarted the computer, the module "mathutils" can be installed.

Comment: @Marouane Amzil -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module "[mathutils](https://github.com/majimboo/py-mathutils#important-details)" is written in portable C, it needs c++ tools to compile it. therefore, after I installed the VS from the link provided in the VS Code terminal and restarted the computer, the module "mathutils" can be installed.

[image]